# ROS Beginner Tutorials: Writing a Simple Service and Client (python) - need some help

Tags: ros, python, service, beginner-tutorials, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm following the **ROS Tutorials** and currently doing the item **Examining the Simple Service and Client** using the **Python** language ((http:// [www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient))).

However when I try to run the client using the python command, I get this error:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv
```

I just can't figure it out what's happening. I'm almost sure I've done all the steps in the previous tutorial ( [link text](http ://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) ), 'cause everything seemed to work just as hoped:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ cd ~/catkin_ws
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/viki/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance,

Batta

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64825/ros-beginner-tutorials:-writing-a-simple-service-and-client-(python)---need-some-help/) by [Batta](https://answers.ros.org/users/5117/batta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-11**:
Did you do step 1.3 of the previous tutorial? http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Building_your_nodes

**Comment by [Batta](https://answers.ros.org/users/5117/batta/) on 2013-06-13**:
Yes, the program built as hoped...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-13**:
I see nothing indicating that beginner_tutorials was built. Is it in your workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was stemming from misspelling in the package name. It's now resolved.

---

Originally posted by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) with karma: 61 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-02-19**:
What was the misspelling? I have seen this mentioned in another question about the same problem so perhaps the misspelling stems from the code give in the tutorial.